# Trouble using prepared statement with select query

Tags: php

Getting the following

mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1 in C:\Users\user\Documents\examplePHP\UAMP\UwAmp\www\php-project\update.php on line 55

Using the following

```
//getting id from url sent from the select.php 
$StaffID = $_GET['StaffID'];


        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Name, Address, Telephone, BusinessID FROM staff WHERE StaffID = ?");

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i",$param_staffid);

            // Set parameters

            $param_staffid = $StaffID;


            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login2 page if successful
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $Name = $row['Name'];
    $Address = $row['Address'];
    $Telephone = $row['Telephone'];
    $BusinessID = $row['BusinessID'];
}
            } 
            else{
                 die("ERROR: Could not insert. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just set `$sql` to the string, not call `mysqli_query()` there.

```
$sql = "SELECT Name, Address, Telephone, BusinessID FROM staff WHERE StaffID = ?";
```

You perform the query when you call `mysqli_stmt_execute()`.

Answer (score 0):

change query to this way :-

```
$sql = "SELECT Name, Address, Telephone, BusinessID FROM staff WHERE StaffID = ?";
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){

    // the rest of your code

if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
{
    // the rest of your code
} 
else
{
    // the rest of your code
}
```

Note:- [check this](https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/mysqli_prepare.php)